# Javascript interfaces / loose coupling

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

In programming languages like PHP a lot of concrete implementation are put behind interfaces so it will be a lot easier to swap out concrete implementations since you are programming to an interface and not to a concretion.

In our project we are wanting to implement a date library called `moment.js` to handle dates for us but there is the concern of being coupled too hard to our code if we implement it in all our javascript.

To create something of an interface in javascript the methods and properties could be wrapped by our own library, this way we can more easily swap out the `concrete` date library we are using just in case.

I am wondering if there is some kind of pattern or standardized way for this in javascript. At first sight it was about just create a library for ourselves where we would put complex re-usable logic that still uses moment.js under the hood.

If we still use `moment.js` functionality here and there we are still tightly coupled to it though. If we do implement some kind of pattern where we can only talk to `moment.js` through an adapter or interface we are stuck implementing wrappers for the entire library which seems absurd.

How do javascript developers deal with this?

Comment: You don't have the same thing in Javascript, but you're more than welcome to shove things behind Facades or Wrappers.

Comment: It is all the same in all programming languages. It depends on how exactly you use Moment, but generally seems to be useless abstraction and antipattern. *How do javascript developers deal with this?* - they just pick a library and write code. Incidentally, Moment is one of safe choices for libraries, there are almost no strong alternatives, and they (e.g. date-fns) don't have a set of third-party plugins.

Comment: @estus so what you are essentially saying is do not worry about any hard coupling but just go ahead and use it straight up, as is?

Comment: That's right. If there are cases when there's a need to swap a library for some reason, you never know this beforehand any way, but Moment for date/time looks like safe bet to me.

Comment: In javascript, there is no interface at all, there aren't even classes. It's a completely prototype-driven architecture. Interfaces are not necessary as there is no such thing as type-safety in js at all. If an object has a method called `xy`, you can call it. If you exchange the object by another one, you don't need to match a predefined interface. If the new object also has the method `xy`, it meets the requirements.

Comment: "*At first sight it was about just create a library for ourselves where we would put complex re-usable logic*" - you should do that nonetheless. And then, this library *is* your adapter to moment.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two approaches to face this problem.

1. Your current approach: *wrapping*.
2. [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) all the way!

### When I would go for the #1 approach of *wrapping*.

Basically you're not comfortable with the library's API style. For example, you're against *fluent APIs* and vice versa. Thus, you wrap the whole library to feel more comfortable and, at the end of the day, when you switch to another one, you'll just need to change wrapper's implementation.

### When I would go for the #2 approach *duck typing all the way*!

You've really understood what are the benefits and drawbacks of dynamically-typed languages, hence you're not intoxicated by strongly-typed languages' approaches, yet you still develop on both programming styles.

Also, you've understood that we developers tend to think that we're goinig to be forced to make technology switches every year, or after 5 years, but it's a wrong behavior as, while *good decisions* aren't forever, they last in a reasonable long time so maybe your system or application might need more than just going from a library to another.

In dynamically-typed languages like JavaScript, we can go ahead and replace the need of *interfaces* with *documentation*. Check the following code snippet:

```
function doStuff(moment) {
    var currentDate = moment(new Date());
}
```

Right, you're injecting `moment`, but nothing prevents you from creating a wrapper once you've realized that you need to swtich to another library, since you know that working with dates is more or less the same with any library. Don't load *momentjs* anymore and develop the whole wrapper, and call your custom code or even a new and fancy library!

```
function moment(date) {
     return {
          date: date,
          ago: () => {
              var date = this.date;

              // do the stuff here to return a text like "3 hours ago"

              return text;
          }
     };
}
```

And you know that this will work unless the blabox doesn't output the expected result by the caller of a given function, right?

Would you scratch your head too much now just because some day you'll want to swtich from *momentjs* to who knows what? Probably not, as you're ok with the *momentjs*'s fluent API and it won't be hard to create alternate implementation starting with a function called the same way and following the same API but exposing a different implementation.

Once your *duck* says *quack!*, who cares if it's still your old duck or younger one?

Do you want another advise? [You're not going to need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it), and if you need it, it's a matter of providing a new duck.

### About loose coupling

IMO, dynamically-typed languages are loosely copupled per se. As there's no other coupling between the caller and the callee than the API identifiers (property names, function names...), implementations are hot-switchable by design.

Perhaps there's an exceptional case: the API has tech-specific connotations. For example, you need to call function called `sendUsingWebSockets` and you don't want to be coupled to an specific communication tech so you wrap that specific function as `send` and some setting defines which is the approach to send data (REST, WebSockets, WebRTC...).

### Answering to some concern explained by the OP in some comment...

> The only question remaining is what would you say to people using a
>   wrapper for mutational purposes? People writing a wrapper method to
>   retrieve a date and mutating it always by prefixing it with something
>   like a string of 'date:' or something alike. I keep telling people
>   that writing an entire wrapper just for cases like this is not worth
>   it since there it no guarantee all the little date instances will be
>   needing the same 'date:' string prefixed.

Web development has evolved a lot during the past 10 years. We're in the UI framework's era and *data-binding* is present in every UI framework since more than 5 years.

Prefixing a date is something tied to an UI requirement and I wouldn't hard-code something like that in an *application service*.

For example, the good old AngularJS 1.x has *directives* and *components* on which you can implement that prefixing without hard-coding prefixes in your models or services:

```
function showDateDirective() {
     return {
         scope: {
             date: "="
         },
         link: (scope, element) {
              element.text(`date: ${scope.date.[call here a formatting function]()}`);
         }
     };
}

module.directive("showDate", showDateDirective);
```

That is, when you need to show a date, you just bind it to some element and that directive would do the rest:

```
<span show-date="model.date"></span>
```

Do you need to change that prefix? Change the directive implementation and you got the work done in few seconds!

Comment: Wow thanks for this in depth answer! `Providing a new duck` in your case would entail going through the codebase and replacing instances of `moment.js` in that case though? I agree fully with your approach and not writing a wrapper ourselves but I am mostly here to convince my co-workers.

Comment: @Stephan-v No problem, you're welcome! So... Hmm, you wouldn't replace instances of `momentjs` but you would leave them all, and you wouldn't load `momentjs` anymore. Instead of that, you would provide another library (either custom or a wrapped one) which would have the same interface *by usage* than `momentjs`.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. Makes a lot of sense. The only question remaining is what would you say to people using a wrapper for mutational purposes? People writing a wrapper method to retrieve a date and mutating it always by prefixing it with something like a string of `'date:'` or something alike. I keep telling people that writing an entire wrapper just for cases like this is not worth it since there it no guarantee all the little date instances will be needing the same `'date:'` string prefixed. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @Stephan-v I'm going to answer this as part of an update of my own answer :D

Comment: @Stephan-v Updated! Let's see if this addresses your concerns!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137639/discussion-between-stephan-v-and-matias-fidemraizer).